# In terms of page speed and DOM numbers, what is the best solution?

Tags: jquery, html, performance

If I have a very long page with an hidden and long `about` section which shows by clicking a menu icon, is it better in terms of performance to leave it inside the `index.html` or to use it as a separate `about.html` and import it using jQuery like this?

```
<script>
    $("#about")
        .html('<object data="http://www.example/about.html"/>');
</script>
```

I forgot to say that I have and want a one page website.
Thanks.
F.

Comment: Using the `object` tag to import part of your website probably isn't the best idea, it would be better to just leave that part in the `index.html` file, or load the HTML with ajax, for instance `$.fn.load`

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to research various approaches to building single page website. There are also javascript frameworks designed for that purpose